# Tomcat7 not starting successfully

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

Hi I just downloaded Tomcat7 for Mac OSX while running startup.sh there are no error. However there is no services running on port 8080. It is starting up something at port 8009 though.

Any suggestions ?

[image]

Comment: The "ajp13" entry on 8009 indicates that Tomcat is actually running. Is there an active java process? What's in the logs (probably /Library/Tomcat7/logs/catalina.*.log)?

Answer (score 0):

After a reboot it magically worked again.